# What is wrong with my I2C link? It toggles LEDS when it shouldn't

Tags: verilog, i2c, led

I have two Lattice chips connected up to my Arduino connected through I2C. The Lattice boards contain 8 LEDs each. My Arduino is the master.

[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDcOx.jpg)

My goal is to drive the LEDs on each board.

So far it's going well, but there are a few bugs. I begin the process by telling the Lattice board, that I am adressing, I am about to send the pins that I want it to drive. I do this by sending a byte set to 10 for now. Following this I send the pins I want it to drive in a byte like this, 10110111, where index 0 is the first LED and index 1 is the second LED and so on and so on through 8.

Verilog code for this:

```
if(adr_match & bit_DATA & data_phase & op_write & getDrive == 1'b1) begin
    drivePins[bitcnt] <= SDAr;
    if (bitcnt == 0) begin
        getDrive = 1'b0;
    end
end

if (adr_match & bit_DATA & data_phase & op_write & (IOout == 10) & bitcnt == 0) getDrive = 1'b1;
```

Lastly I send a byte, an 11 that tells the Lattice board that its set and to drive the pins connected to the 8 LEDs.

```
if (adr_match & bit_DATA & data_phase & op_write & IOout == 11 & bitcnt == 0) begin
    led0 = drivePins[0];
    led1 = drivePins[1];
    led2 = drivePins[2];
    led3 = drivePins[3];
    led4 = drivePins[4];
    led5 = drivePins[5];
    led6 = drivePins[6];
    led7 = drivePins[7];
end
```

The rest of the code is based of this implementation for an I2C slave [here](http://www.fpga4fun.com/I2Cslave1.html).

My problem is that if I send the drivePins byte from the Arduino, with a 1 in the first index (ex. 0000110 **0**), then it freaks out and turns on LEDs that it shouldn't. The LED pattern ends up looking like this: 11110110, from just this 11111110. So does anyone know what's going on?

On th Arduino I'm using th Wire Library.

```
Wire.beginTransmission(2);
Wire.write(10);
Wire.endTransmission();

Wire.beginTransmission(2);
Wire.write(~(10101011));
Wire.endTransmission();

Wire.beginTransmission(2);
Wire.write(11);
Wire.endTransmission();
```

The transmisiion looks like this.

Comment: Numbers default to integer types. == 10 is equal to ten. I am not sure if you meant 2'b10.

Comment: The 10 is supposed to be equal to ten

Comment: You should definitely simulate this and see the results, also, without the complete code, it is hard to say what is wrong with that code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was running the code on bitcnt 0. It didn't update the 0th index in the byte. I sent a 9h bit, an ACk bit, following my data byte and ran the code on recieving that byte.

Answer (score 0):

My answer might be completely off, as much information is missing from the question, but the problem caused in the least significant bit makes me think that you might have some confusion with the I2C address. Can you please check that the master sends commands like this:

Start - Lattice1AddressWrite(lsb==0) - 0x0A - LedPatterSingleByte - 0x0B - Stop

Having multiple starts or stops will change the meaning of the bytes.

If this is not addressing your problem, can you please provide some information/pseudo code, of the master. I need some info to put this into context.